# Print the object and check null

Tags: java

```
public void printManagerAvailable(Manager mgr) {
    System.out.println(" Is Manager object available : " + mgr!=null);
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

Why output is only `true` here? I'm expecting:

```
Is Manager object available : true
```

Comment: I don't  want to print mgr . I just want to know if Manager is null or available in logs . I used String.valueOf(mgr) gives me the expected output .  "Is Manager object available : true" . I want to understand why do i get only boolean value if I just print  "System.out.println(" Is Manager object available : " + mgr!=null);"

Answer (score 5):

because it thinks that you are saying `" Is Manager object available : " + mgr` is all to the left of `!= null`. In other words, it does `" Is Manager object available : " + mgr` first and then it compares `" Is Manager object available : [Object:Manager]" != null`.

Do this.

```
Manager mgr = new Manager();
    mgr.setChangeClass(5);
    mgr.setChangeClockIn(10);
    System.out.println(" Is Manager object available : " + (mgr!=null));
```

Comment: @Venkata Pavan Does that make since?

Comment: Thanks that really helps.

Comment: You are expecting it to concatenate the string with the result of the Boolean output, but it reads it from left to right so the first thing it sees is `" Is Manager object available : " + mgr`. so it tries to concatenate the string and the Manager Object into a new string. It then takes that new string and checks that it is not `null`. The the result of `new_string != null` is `true`. That is why it only returns `true`.

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help. Could you please mark the questions as answered? You can do that by clicking the check mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers cover what is happening, this is why it is happening:

The order of [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) in Java puts addition, `+`, ahead of equality, `!=`.

It's important to realize that it's not caused by left-to-right ordering here.

So what you have is applying the operators in the order like so:

```
("Is null : " + mgr) != null
```

And to fix it you can use brackets to force the precedence the other way:

```
"Is null : " + (mgr != null)
```

Comment: Thanks I got you. I know as the Manager is initialized it will never return false above. I just took it as a example.

Comment: @VenkataPavan Ok, well I adjusted your example, removed the lines that had nothing to do with your question and made it possible it could be `null`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this line of code.

```
System.out.println(" Is Manager object available : " + (mgr == null ? "is null" : "not null"));
```

Comment: He want's the result to ether be `" Is Manager object available : true"` or `" Is Manager object available : false"`. Simply putting the `mgr!=null` into parenthesizes will do the trick.